# Is there a way to speed up gun.js sync?

Tags: gun

I am making game for my kids.  I want them to control an abacus input on their iPad and a number-pad input on their iphone.  The overall game-boad is on the iPad.  The phone is just used to separate the number pad for ergonomics.  To facilitate communication between the phone and the ipad - I store and sync with gun.js (server and clients).

It works, but the gun.js sync is a bit slow.  Good enough for text messages, but not good enough to game.

Have I run into a common first time gunner pitfall?  Is there a config that I missed to increase cycle frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 important pieces to this solution.

1. turn off cloudflare caching.
2. stop making silly mistakes.

Comment: Glad you found your own answer. Though note, if different devices are out of sync with clocks, you'll see artificial delays. Some devices don't do NTP correctly, so GUN has a p2p clock sync module called NTS you can opt into.

Comment: Hi @marknadal - The issue came back when I went to production.  It seems to be pm2 --watch not liking socket long polls.

Comment: interesting, have you been able to debug any further?

Comment: Hi @marknadal - I just don't --watch anymore as a temporary solution.  However, I think there are better solutions by searching for information on pm2 for socketio and/or other long polls.